# Получение числа из k-нотации: 1kkk -> 1000000000

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Помогите пожалуйста создать простую функцию, в которую мы будем передавать 1 аргумент а именно строку. Эта функция должна служить что бы пользователь мог сокращенно вводить огромные числа к примеру (1k - 1000, 1.5kk - 1500000, 1kkk - 1000000000) мне маленький набросок а дальше я сам попробую, спасибо

Comment: Если `s` строка, то `n = float(s.rstrip('k')) * 1000 ** s.count('k')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [numexpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html):

```
import numexpr as ne

def to_num(s):
    s = (s.lower()
          .replace('k', '*10**3')
          .replace('m', '*10**6')
          .replace('g', '*10**9')
          .replace('t', '*10**12'))
    return ne.evaluate(s).item()
```

Примеры:

```
In [222]: print(to_num('1kKk'))
1000000000

In [223]: print(to_num('1m'))
1000000

In [224]: print(to_num('123.45m'))
123450000.0

In [225]: print(to_num('123.45m'))
123450000.0

In [226]: print(to_num('0.5k'))
500.0

In [227]: print(to_num('1K'))
1000
```

Answer (score 4):

Находим индекс первого символа `k` в строке и разделяем строку по индексу

Пример:

```
def k_to_number(num_str: str) -> int:
    i = num_str.index('k')
    num, size = num_str[:i], len(num_str[i:])
    return int(float(num) * (1000 ** size))

print(k_to_number("1k"))     # 1000
print(k_to_number("1.5kk"))  # 1500000
print(k_to_number("1kkk"))   # 1000000000
```

---

Ответ **MaxU** мне напомнил о похожем способе, с которым нужно быть очень осторожным:

```
def k_to_number(num_str: str) -> int:
    return int(eval(num_str.replace('k', '*10**3')))
```

Дело в том, что `eval` (и его аналог `exec`) выполняют внутри себя питоничий код и это опасно, особенно, когда строки передаются из-вне.